# WPF Virtualization breaks if width or height too low

Tags: wpf, virtualization

I have an ListView control which when the width/height of the parent UserControl is below a certain value stops virtualizing (suddenly requesting all ItemsSource elements, not only the ones visible).

```
<ListView x:Name="ResultsListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Results.SearchResults}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      Template="{DynamicResource ListBoxControlTemplate1}"
                      Background="CornflowerBlue" Height="{Binding ElementName=MyExpander, Path=Height}">
```

I did set an MinWidth, MinHeight for the whole application in my App.xaml to stop that behavior, but I would love to know why the ListView stops virtualizing.

Comment: The virtualization runs off of what you should be able to see on the screen, if your elements 'fail' to show because of the size of the control then the virtualization runs through the entire dataset looking for visible controls so it isn't that its stopped virtualization. i'd focus on your item template and see if something there would cause the height and width checks to fail if below a certain size, note that Visualization actually draws the controls rather than just estimating them, this means that a failed virtualization can still be a successful Visualization

Comment: Try to set the Height property to a fixed size: <ListBox ... Height="100" />. Or bind to the *Actual*Height property of a control.